# How to get the maximum virtual set size of a unix process during its lifetime?

Tags: unix, process

The `time` command includes a format parameter "M", which according to the `time` man page on Linux is used for the following:

```
Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.
```

However, it does not look like `time` is able to measure the maximum virtual set size of a process during its lifetime. How can I achieve this on Linux?

Comment: VSZ is not the same as Maximum Virtual Set Size.  The former is sum of pages mapped into process space by the memory manager and the later is a process limit..i.e. MinVSZ < VSZ < MaxVSZ.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've corrected it, thanks. Any other guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: removed answer to a question that wasn't asked.

Looks like the way to do this would be to parse out `VmPeak` from `/prod/[pid]/status`. See [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me what the field name is in the struct? I'm having trouble locating the one for vsz. Also, is this the documentation for the rusage struct? http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question.